# The use of sizeof in the implementation of QScopedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, sizeof, qscopedpointer

To understand how Qt prevent incomplete type I went through the header file of `qscopedpointer.h`.The related part is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct QScopedPointerDeleter
{
    static inline void cleanup(T *pointer)
    {
        // Enforce a complete type.
        // If you get a compile error here, read the section on forward declared
        // classes in the QScopedPointer documentation.
        typedef char IsIncompleteType[ sizeof(T) ? 1 : -1 ];
        (void) sizeof(IsIncompleteType);

        delete pointer;
    }
};
```

I know when using `sizeof` on incomplete type the compilation will fail.But what do the array and second `sizeof` do? Is sizeof alone not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is used so the negative size of it will give a compile time error. The second line makes sure the compiler can't skip the evaluation of `sizeof(T)` by ensuring the actual size of `IsIncompleteType` is used.

Comment: thx, does this mean some compilers evaluate an incomplete type to be 0-sized?

Comment: i'm not sure if that `sizeof`-expression has a value at all for the compiler. msvc gives *error C2027: use of undefined type T* \*and\* *error C2118: negative subscript*